# Synchronise Oracle database with Google Cloud

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to get my Oracle DB content into GCP - BigQuery specifically, and then keep both in synch. I have not been able to find a standard way of doing this using GCP tools without using third-party software. Has anyone tried this? Any recommendations?

Comment: Here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/dw2bq/oracle/oracle-bq-migration-guide.pdf?hl=ja) for Oralce DB to BQ migration. are you looking for this?

Comment: There is no standard integration to keep both sync. In my previous company, we extracted regularly the latest updates in the table to extract fhem, make  a file and send it to Cloud Storage. However, that require an update on your side (add last update date on each date) and you have to create the process to extract the data. If you don't use third party software, you have to re create it!!